# Solution $x^{73}+x^{48}+x^{26} \equiv 0$ mod $13$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve $x^{73}+x^{48}+x^{26} \equiv 0$ mod $13$. Can I say that By Fermat’s Little Theorem I have $x^{12} \equiv 1$ mod $13$? If I am correct remaining part will be simple but otherwise I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: another solution is $$x=3$$ or $$x=9$$

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Euler's theorem (assuming $x$ is a positive natural number less than $13$ :-)(as the comments below point out $x\equiv 0\mod13\;$ is a solution)
$$
x^{a}\equiv x^{a\mod \phi(13)}\equiv x^{a\mod 12}\mod 13
$$
Therefore our equation turns into
$$
x+1+x^2\equiv 0\mod 13
$$
A little experimentation leads to the solution $x=3$ and this leads to the factorization
$$x^2+x+1=(x-9)(x-3)\mod13$$

Comment: or $x$ is 0 of course

Comment: Don't forget $x \equiv 0 \bmod 13$.